# Calculations between two columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame called cleancc in the following format:

```
Education  Status
College    Default
College    No Default
HS         Default
PHD        No Default
HS         No Default
College    No Default
```

I'd like to perform some calculations which look at the Default rate based on Education level.  For example, something like this.

```
Education  Def NDef  DefRate
HS         1   1     50.00%
College    1   2     33.33%
PHD        0   1     0.00%
```

The following code gets me the count for each Education level.

```
table(cleancc$Education)
```

I'm struggling with how to link these to the Status column and create the table showing default rate.

Answer (score 2):

Using the base R function, `addmargins`, which takes a table as input and has a function argument, we can do

```
addmargins(table(dat), 2, FUN = list("perc"=function(x) x[1] / sum(x)))
         Status
Education   Default No Default      perc
  College 1.0000000  2.0000000 0.3333333
  HS      1.0000000  1.0000000 0.5000000
  PHD     0.0000000  1.0000000 0.0000000
```

We wrap the function in a list in order to provide a reasonable name.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the ever-helpful **`dplyr`** package to perform this aggregation:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(Education) %>%
    summarise(Def = sum(Status == 'Default'),
              NDef = sum(Status != 'Default'),
              DefRate = mean(Status == 'Default'))

  Education   Def  NDef   DefRate
      <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1   College     1     2 0.3333333
2        HS     1     1 0.5000000
3       PHD     0     1 0.0000000
```

We could also use the `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(Status ~ Education, data = dat, FUN = function(x){
    c('Def' = sum(x == 'Default'),
    'NDef' = sum(x != 'Default'),
    'DefRate' = mean(x == 'Default')
    )
})

  Education Status.Def Status.NDef Status.DefRate
1   College  1.0000000   2.0000000      0.3333333
2        HS  1.0000000   1.0000000      0.5000000
3       PHD  0.0000000   1.0000000      0.0000000
```

#### data

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(Education = c("College", "College", "HS", "PHD", 
"HS", "College"), Status = c("Default", "No Default", "Default", 
"No Default", "No Default", "No Default")), .Names = c("Education", 
"Status"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cleancc <- read.table(text = "
  'Education'  'Status'
  'College'    'Default'
  'College'    'No Default'
  'HS'         'Default'
  'PHD'        'No Default'
  'HS'         'No Default'
  'College'    'No Default'", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

cleancc %>%
  group_by(Education) %>%
  summarize(Def = sum(Status == 'Default'),
            NDef = sum(Status == 'No Default'),
            DefRate = Def / (Def + NDef))
```

Comment: How is your solution any different than mine (other than being posted after I posted my solution)?

Comment: It isn't. You must have posted yours as I was writing mine. Are you suggesting that I copied yours?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting that you copied my answer.